# Не работают сессии

Tags: php, mysql

После отправки сообщения выскакивает: "Вход на эту страницу разрешен только зарегистрированным пользователям!" Если убрать первую половину кода? то все работает, только не добавляется запись `author` в БД, и получатель не видит письма, хотя оно в БД заносится.

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../core/init.php';
if (!empty($_SESSION['username']) and !empty($_SESSION['password'])) {
    $login    = $_SESSION['username'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];
    $result2  = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$login' AND `password`='$password' AND `active`='1'");
    $myrow2   = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    if (empty($myrow2['user_id'])) {
        exit("Вход на эту страницу разрешен только зарегистрированным пользователям!");
    }
} else {
    exit("Вход на эту страницу разрешен только зарегистрированным пользователям!");
}

if (isset($_POST['user_id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['user_id'];
}
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
    $text = $_POST['text'];
}
if (isset($_POST['poluchatel'])) {
    $poluchatel = $_POST['poluchatel'];
}
$author = $_SESSION['username'];
$date   = date("Y-m-d");

$text = stripslashes($text);
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);

$result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages` (`author`, `poluchatel`, `date`, `text`) VALUES ('$author','$poluchatel','$date','$text')"); //заносим в базу сообщение

echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='1; URL=index.php?user_id=" . $id . "'></head></html>"; //перенаправляем пользователя
?>
```

Comment: А куки вы не воспринимаете?

Comment: не вижу кода авторизации, в нем скорей всего и есть проблема. попробуйте сделать print_r($_SESSION), уверен что массив будет либо пустой либо с другими ключами.

Comment: Выбрось курсы попова!

Comment: На кой вам хранить пароль в сессии? О_о

     $_POST['poluchatel']; // 1C всему голова :)

Comment: function VstavitVTablicuBazyDannyh($avtor, $poluchatel, $data, $tekst) ...

Answer (score 1):

По коду и по ошибке можно сделать вывод: поля password и login установлены. Далее происходит запрос из базы: если такого пользователя нет, то выдать ошибку, которую вы видите, и, независимо от этого, сообщение заносится в базу. Соответсвенно проблема в сохранённых login и password. Возможно в сессии пароль незашифрованный, а в базе шифрованный? Сверьте значение сессии со значениями в базе:
 1. Для сессии после строчки

```
 if (!empty($_SESSION['username']) and !empty($_SESSION['password'])) {
Напишите: echo $_SESSION['username'] . ' = ' . $_SESSION['password'];
```

1. Для базы, в таблице где хранятся пользователи выполните запрос: SELECT * FROM таблица_пользователей WHERE поле_login = ваш_логин